# How to cancel Everyplay SDK recording when app goes to background?

Tags: ios, iphone, video-capture, everyplay

I am using Everyplay SDK to record video in my game. I observed when everyplay records video and app is backgrounded/suspended using iPhone's home button, Everyplay suspends the recording and resumes it when app returns to foreground. I want to stop the recording completely whenever user suspends the app and recording should not start again when foregrounded.

I am calling

```
[[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] stopRecording];
```

when recording and my app receives **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification** but it doesn't help. Everyplay suspends and restarts it automatically when active.

How can I stop the recording completely?

Comment: Have you tried to stop Everyplay in your AppDelegate's applicationWillResignActive method ? This would guarantee that the stop is called before Everyplay receives the  UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification since app delegate suspend/resume methods are called before notifications.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. I am trying to stop the recording in a View Controller when **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification** NSNotification is received. I am going to try that right now.

Comment: Ok. I have tested this again and tried to stop Everyplay recording in AppDelegate's applicationWillResignActive method. Result is same i.e recording automatically resumes when app reactivates.

Comment: I tested it too, you are right. However I found a way to get around the problem. Posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to wait for the recording thread to fully stop. You must also do the stop in your AppDelegate's applicationWillResignActive method.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] stopRecording];
    while([[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] isRecording]) {
        NSLog(@"Waiting for recording thread to stop.");
    }
...
```

Comment: I have used a different approach as a work around to this problem. I created a NSTimer (of 1 second duration) when my app comes to foreground and repeatedly check if recording is started. If it starts recording, I stop it explicitly and invalidate the timer. If I need to start recording, I invalidate the timer if still running and then start the recording. Don't know if my method is good or bad   but is working fine.

Comment: Everyplay 1.7.2 contains fixes related to pause/resume behaviour on suspend. The while loop or timer hack is probably no longer needed.

Comment: Does Everyplay cancel the recording automatically when app go into background or do I need to add some code for that? I have already upgraded the Everyplay SDK to 1.7.2(haven't made any changes to code) but my timer hack is still kicking out the resumed recording.

Comment: If you don't stop or pause manually on suspend, Everyplay will just continue recording when returning from the background.

Comment: Yes! it looks like recording isn't starting when app resumes. The My timer hack is now stopping my actual (intentional) recording after resume.